# Factoring constant rank maps into a submersion and an immersion

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, implicit-function-theorem

Let $X$ and $Z$ be smooth manifolds and $\phi: X \to Z$ a smooth map so that the differential $D \phi$ is everywhere of rank $d$. Is there necessarily a $d$-fold $Y$ so that $\phi$ factors as a submersion $X \to Y$ followed by an immersion $Y \to Z$?

I have no real motivation, it just seemed like a natural question. Notice that we can't assume $Y \to Z$ is injective: Consider mapping $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ by $(x,y) \mapsto ((x-1)^2 (x+1), (x-1)(x+1)^2)$, whose image is a nodal cubic.

Comment: Isn't it an immediate consequence of the "rank theorem"?

Comment: @IgorRivin All the sources I found only said that this is locally true: I.e., for any $x \in X$, there is an open $U \ni x$ where I can make such a factorization. It doesn't seem obvious to me how to glue all of these into a global $Y$.

Comment: There is something called the global constant rank theorem, but it only says that, for each $z \in Z$, the fiber $\pi^{-1}(z)$ is a submanifold of $X$. It doesn't say that the connected components of the $\phi^{-1}(z)$'s can be organized into a manifold.

Comment: Presumably, the way you'd want to do this is to define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $X$ by $x_1 \sim x_2$ if $\phi(x_1) = \phi(x_2)$ and $x_1$ and $x_2$ are in the same connected component of $\phi^{-1}(\phi(x_1))$. Then show that $X/\sim$ is a smooth manifold. But this seemed hard to me, which was when I decided to ask.

Comment: Well, I might be confused (quite likely), but the constant rank theorem seems to say that the image of your map is an immersed submanifold of $Z.$ Call it $Y.$ The map $X\rightarrow Y$ is a constant rank map which is surjective. That makes it a submersion (this is a theorem in Lee's book, page 83 I believe).

Comment: @DavidSpeyer:  In fact, $X/$~ as you define it need not be a (Hausdorf) smooth manifold.  Let $X$ be $\mathbb{R}^2$ minus the point $(0,0)$, and let $\phi:X\to \mathbb{R}$ be $\phi(x,y) = x$.  then $\phi^{-1}\bigl(\phi(0,1)\bigr)$ has two components, while $\phi^{-1}\bigl(\phi(a,y)\bigr)$ has only one component for $a\not=0$.  The resulting $X/$~ will not be Hausdorf.  (Note, though that this $\phi:X\to Z$ does not provide a counterexample to your original question.)

Comment: There is a topological theorem treating this situation in the category of topological spaces, it is called "monotone -light factorization". If you follow the proof in your setting you should get the desired result (but I did not check the details).

Comment: What if you define your equivalence relation on $X$ as $x_1 \sim x_2$ if $\phi(x_1)=\phi(x_2)$ and there exists an open nbhd of $x_1 \cup x_2 $  such that $\phi$ restricted to that neighborhood is up to diffeomorphism a linear projection followed by a linear inclusion? I think this works (though really haven't checked).

Comment: @IgorRivin I'm looking though Lee's book at http://webmath2.unito.it/paginepersonali/sergio.console/lee.pdf . I didn't find the Theorem you reference, but I did find Exercise 5-13, which makes this claim. At first I thought this had to be wrong, (think about the line mapping to a nodal cubic) but then I checked his definition of immersed submanifold (p. 119). His definition is very generous: It just says that $\phi(X)$ can be given some topology such that $\phi(X) \to Z$ is an injective immersion. (continued)

Comment: So Exercise 5-13 is true, but the map $X \to Y$ may not be continuous with respect to the topology for $Y \to Z$ is an immersion. (Again, think about the line mapping to a nodal cubic.)

Comment: @DavidSpeyer:  But in the case of the nodal cubic that you give above, one shouldn't take $Y$ to be equal to $\phi(X)$ anyway.  Instead, take $Y = \mathbb{R}$ and $\phi = \iota\circ\sigma$, where the map $\sigma:X\to Y$ is just $\sigma(x,y) = x$ while $\iota:Y\to Z$ is just $\iota(x) = \bigl((x{-}1)^2(x{+}1),(x{+}1)^2(x{-}1)\bigr)\ \ $.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A smooth factorization does not exist in all cases.

Let $X$ be $\mathbb{R}^2$ minus the closed ray $R = \{ (x,0)\ |\ x\ge 0\}$, and define $\phi:X\to\mathbb{R}^2 = Z$ by the rule
$$
\phi(x,y) = \begin{cases}(x,0), & \text{when $x\le 0$,}\\ 
\bigl(x,\phantom{-}e^{-1/x^2}\bigr), & \text{when $x> 0$ and $y>0$.}\\
\bigl(x,-e^{-1/x^2}\bigr), & \text{when $x> 0$ and $y<0$.} \end{cases}
$$
Then $D\phi = \phi'$ has rank $1$ everywhere on $X$, but there is no smooth manifold $Y$ for which there is a smooth submersion $\sigma:X\to Y$ and a smooth immersion $\iota:Y\to Z$ such that $\phi = \iota\circ\sigma$.

(Proof: Since $X$ is connected, one can assume that $Y$, if such existed, be connected.  Now, considering the map $\pi:Z\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $\pi(x,y)=x$, one sees that $\pi\circ\phi:X\to\mathbb{R}$ is a surjective submersion.  If the desired factorization existed, then since $\pi\circ\phi = (\pi\circ\iota)\circ\sigma$, the Chain Rule would imply that $\pi\circ\iota:Y\to\mathbb{R}$ be a (surjective) local diffeomorphism.  Since $Y$ is connected and $1$-dimensional, it would follow that $\pi\circ\iota:Y\to\mathbb{R}$ be a diffeomorphism, which is impossible since $\pi\circ\iota$ cannot be one-to-one.)

Comment: Thanks! That does it, then. My only thought for a hypothesis to add that might save the day is to ask that $\phi: X \to Z$ be proper.

Answer (score 3):

The point of this answer is to note that the quotient $X/\sim$ is locally Euclidean (though, as pointed out above, not Hausdorff). To recall notation, $\phi: X \to Z$ is the map of constant rank and $\sim$ is the equivalence relation on $X$ where $x_1 \sim x_2$ iff $\phi(x_1) = \phi(x_2) =: z$ and $x_1$ and $x_2$ are in the same connected component of $\phi^{-1}(z)$. This may have been obvious to everyone else, but I didn't see it for a while.

The constant rank theorem tells us that $X$ can be covered by open sets $U_i$ where we can locally write $\phi$ as $U_i \overset{\pi_i}{\longrightarrow} V_i \overset{\iota_i}{\longrightarrow} W_i$, where $U$, $V$ and $W$ are open sets in $\mathbb{R}^m$, $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$, the map $\pi_i$ is projection onto the first $d$ coordinates and the map $\iota_i$ is inclusion of the first $d$-coordinates. Replacing $U_i$ and $V_i$ by smaller open sets, we may assume that $U_i \cong V_i \times D_i$ with $D_i$ an open ball, and $\pi_i$ the projection onto $V_i$. Thus, $U_i/\sim$ will be isomorphic to $V_i$.

So, $X/\sim$ will be glued from the $V_i$, and the map from each $V_i \to X/\sim$ will be an inclusion. But it wasn't obvious to me at first that the image of $V_i$ in $X$ will open. Once we establish this, the $V_i$ will give Euclidean patches on $X/\sim$.

Let's fix two of these open sets, $V_a$ and $V_b$. We must show that the part of $V_b$ which is $\sim$-identified with points in $X$ will be open; this establishes that $V_a$ is open in $X/\sim$.

Now, the fibers of $\phi$ will be manifolds, so we can replace "connected" with "path connected" in the definition of $\sim$. This means that if $x_1 \in U_a$ is equivalent to $x_2 \in U_b$, there must be a path from $x_1$ to $x_2$ on which $\phi$ is constant. Said path will be compact, so we can cover it with finitely many $U_i$. For each sequence $(a, c_0, c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_r, b)$ of indices, let $U(a, c_1, \ldots, c_r, b)$ be the set of points $x$ of $U_b$ such that there is a path starting in $U_a$ and passing through $U_{c_1}$, ..., $U_{c_r}$, $U_b$, ending at $x$. Clearly, $U(a, c_1, \ldots, c_r, b)$ is a union of $\sim$ equivalence classes in $U_b$, write $V(a, c_1, \ldots, c_r, b)$ for the quotient in $V_b$. The part of $V_b$ which is identified with $V_a$ is $\bigcup_{c_1 \ldots, c_r} V(a, c_1, \ldots, c_r, b)$. So it is enough to show that $V(a, c_1, \ldots, c_r, b)$ is open.

This last is pretty straightforward but annoying to write out, so I think I'll skip it unless someone tells me they want it.

Comment: Did you ever work out what demanding $phi$ be proper gave?

Comment: @DavidRoberts No.